# How can I use acf() for mutliple subsets in R?

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying write code that will do autocorrelation for multiple subsets. For example. I have health data for multiple countries over time. I want to get each country's autocorrelation for each variable. Any help would be great!
Here are some things I have tried, unsuccessfully:

```
require(plyr)
POP_ACF=acf(PhD_data_list_view$POP, lag.max=NULL, type=c("correlation"), 
            plot=TRUE, na.action=na.pass, demean=TRUE)

dlply(PhD_data_list_view, .(Country), function(x) POP_ACF %+% x)

POP_ACF=function(PhD_data_list_view$POP) c(acf(PhD_data_list_view$POP, plot=TRUE)$acf)
```

Answer (score 0):

`acf` is a function takes a vector and returns a list. That makes it a natural fit for the `purrr` package, which maps functions over lists, but it can also be done using base R.

I'll use the `beaver1` dataset from the `datasets` package since you didn't provide yours. I'll use different days of observations as the analogue to your different countries, and temperature for your POP variable.

## Base R:

- `split` turns the vector `beaver1$temp` into a list of vectors along the second argument, `beaver1$day`.
- Then `mapply` runs the function `acf` on each element of that list.
- Since we're using `mapply` instead of `lapply`, we can also provide another list of arguments, here the titles for each plot, `main = unique(beaver1$day)`.
- The last argument, `SIMPLIFY = F`, tells it to return the default output, not attempt to coerce the list into anything else.

---

```
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
mapply(acf, 
       split(beaver1$temp, beaver1$day), 
       main = unique(beaver1$day), 
       SIMPLIFY = F)

# $`346`
# 
# Autocorrelations of series ‘dots[[1L]][[1L]]’, by lag
# 
#     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19 
# 1.000 0.838 0.698 0.593 0.468 0.355 0.265 0.167 0.113 0.069 0.028 0.037 0.087 0.108 0.145 0.177 0.151 0.125 0.123 0.106 

# $`347`
# 
# Autocorrelations of series ‘dots[[1L]][[2L]]’, by lag
# 
#      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13 
#  1.000  0.546  0.335  0.130  0.080  0.024 -0.025 -0.103 -0.090 -0.032  0.168  0.036 -0.089 -0.306
```

[image]

## `purrr` and the tidy way:

This way is a bit more flexible depending what you want to do with the output. We can use `purrr::map` as a direct drop-in for `mapply`:

```
library(purrr)

beaver1 %>% 
  split(.$day) %>% 
  map(~acf(.$temp, main = unique(.$day)))
```

Which returns the exact same output. But we can also go fully tidy and return the data from `acf` as a dataframe so that we can explore it further with `ggplot2`.

- The first `map` is returning a list of outputs, each of which is a list containing, among other things, variables **lag**, **acf**, and **n.used**.
- The `map_dfr` is running the function `data.frame`, assigning each of those variables to a new column.
- We also make a column to calculate the CIs. Refer to: [How is the confidence interval calculated for the ACF function?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211628/how-is-the-confidence-interval-calculated-for-the-acf-function)
- Then we can use `ggplot` to make any kind of plot we want, and we still have the data for any other analysis you want to do.

---

```
library(ggplot2)
beaver_acf <-
  beaver1 %>% 
    split(.$day) %>% 
    map(~acf(.$temp, plot = F)) %>% 
    map_dfr(
      ~data.frame(lag = .$lag, 
                  acf = .$acf,
                  ci = qnorm(0.975)/sqrt(.$n.used)
            ), .id = "day") 

head(beaver_acf)

#   day lag       acf        ci
# 1 346   0 1.0000000 0.2054601
# 2 346   1 0.8378889 0.2054601
# 3 346   2 0.6983476 0.2054601
# 4 346   3 0.5928198 0.2054601
# 5 346   4 0.4680912 0.2054601
# 6 346   5 0.3554939 0.2054601


ggplot(beaver_acf, aes(lag, acf)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = lag, yend = 0)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = ci), linetype = "dashed", color = "blue") +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = -ci), linetype = "dashed", color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Brian. I tried all three methods and they work until missing values come up. The following error comes up:                             Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object.  I then tried:                                                                                                  par(mfrow=c(1,2))
> mapply(acf(na.action = na.pass),
+        split(PhD_data_list_view$POP, PhD_data_list_view$Country),
+        main=unique(PhD_data_list_view$Country),
+        SIMPLIFY = F)       >>>this gives: Error in as.ts(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: You could try removing NAs beforehand. Also, if you have an argument to pass to `acf`, do that in the `mapply(..., na.action=...)` call.