# How do I write a loop or function to create correlograms for subsets of data (using R)?

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am working with R in this situation. We applied a mixed-effects model and are looking at the residuals. I want to see if there is autocorrelation at the plot-level. I will be running the same approach for multiple datasets with many plots and I want to make the approach more efficient.

First, I applied the acf function to for each plot, using code similar to:

```
Plot_acf<-mapply(acf,
                 split(Results$RC,Results$Plot),
                 main=unique(Results$Plot),
                 lag.max=24,
                 SIMPLIFY = F)
```

In this case, the input dataframe ("Results") contains the raw conditional residuals ("RC") for each observation date ('Obs") by plot ("Plot"). It is structured similar to the following:

| Plot | Obs | RC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.432233833 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.421217552 |
| 1 | 3 | 0.825195553 |
| 1 | 4 | 0.526700124 |
| 1 | 5 | 0.993194571 |
| 2 | 1 | 0.600875928 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.534867298 |
| 2 | 3 | 0.652493816 |
| 2 | 4 | 0.149692756 |
| 2 | 5 | 0.824548398 |
| 3 | 1 | 0.030335731 |
| 3 | 2 | 0.036215887 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.950054452 |
| 3 | 4 | 0.744283559 |
| 3 | 5 | 0.177346498 |
| 4 | 1 | 0.835881406 |
| 4 | 2 | 0.574040068 |
| 4 | 3 | 0.935897319 |
| 4 | 4 | 0.959463954 |
| 4 | 5 | 0.954663448 |

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fGDM.png)

The above code creates a list of lists and prints each correlogram with the plot name. Each sub-list within this list contains the results of the autocorrelation function applied to residuals for a certain study plot. This is similar to what I want the end result to be.

**I would like to have an approach that I could apply to similar datasets and I would like to accomplish two things:

1. I would like to create a dataframe that provides the autocorrelation results for each plot in separate columns with the observation number as another column.
2. I would like to print out the correlograms with specific graph characteristics. Given the number of plots, it is not efficient to run this separately for each plot. Essentially, I want a similar result to what the above code creates but I want to be able to specify the characteristics of the correlogram (y-axis limits, title, CI, etc.).
   **

I'm not sure how to structure a loop to complete this process. I would like a function or loop that executes the following for each plot:

```
#calculate confidence interval
CI<-qnorm(1+0.95)/2/sqrt(n)

#plot correlogram for each plot (same as what is accomplished by "Plot_acf" above)
##ci.col="white" is used because I want to substitute an updated CI when there are NAs in the dataset

APlot<-Results[Results$Plot=="3",]
acf<-acf(APlot$RC,na.action=na.pass)    
plot(acf, ylim=c(-1,1),xlim=c(0.5,24), main="Plot number", ci.col='white') 
abline(h=CI,lty=2,col='blue') #so it displays the calculated confidence interval ("CI")
abline(h=-CI,lty=2,col='blue')
```

Additionally, in order to create the dataframe from the list, I have tried:

```
df<-(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(Plot_acf,as.vector))))
```

This creates a dataframe containing lists for the results of the autocorrelation function (acf, type, n.used, lag,series,snames) for each plot. I have tried unnest(df) and unlist(df) but neither seem to work in this case.

Comment: I found this post, which I think offers a better approach using purrr: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659320/how-can-i-use-acf-for-mutliple-subsets-in-r